# Div overlayed over background without stopping scroll

Tags: php, html, overlay

I would like a div that overlays purple over the background image (#page) to cover the entire page rather than just a percentage of the page. At the moment it covers the page if the page does not scroll but as soon as a page requires the user to scroll this happens:

http://darynjohnson.com/Medical%20Futures/winners.php

I tried changing the position to static but that stopped scrolling completely.

SOLVED: Just changed the purple div to overflow: scroll; - thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to set your background image to fixed. You can do this like that:

```
<body background="yourimage.jpg" bgproperties="fixed">
```

You could also let your background move with the content using CSS. The following lines would do that:

```
<style type="text/css">
body
{
      background-image:url('yourbackground.jpg');
      background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Setting the purple div to fixed stops the page scrolling entirely

Answer (score 0):

You can have the purple in another div so for example.

```
<style>
body { background: img 'yoururl.jpg'; }
#purple {background-color: rgba(120,46,134,0.6);}
</style>

<body>
<div id="purple">
your content
</div>
</body>
```